# Estimating transition probability from a state to itself with the MSM package

Tags: r, markov-process, transition-matrix

For a given panel dataset I have used the MSM package to estimate transition probabilities between states. Using the `pnext.msm` function I can obtain the probabilities of getting from a given state $r$ to a state $s$. However, I am also interested in the transition probability of going to $r$ from $r$. The help page for `pnext.msm` states that

> For a continuous-time Markov process in state r, the probability that the next state is s is $-q_{rs} / q_{rr}$, where $q_{rs}$ is the transition intensity (qmatrix.msm).

This seems not well-defined when $r = s$.

I know that I can obtain the transition probabilities for a given time window using the `pmatrix.msm` function, but then the question is what time window I should pick so that I can extract the right $r \rightarrow r$ transition probabilities.

How can I extract the right probability of going from any state $r$ to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Use the Kolmogorow-Smirnov test to identify a time window such that the eigenvalues of the Transition matrix is not sensitive to the precise choice of window.

### Longer Answer

In Markov theory, there are two ways of formulating the dynamics.

1. Continuous time: We talk about transition rates in units of inverse time. So $Q_{rs}$ is the number of transitions from $r$ to $s$ expected per unit time (e.g. 5 transitions per second).
2. Discrete time. Here we talk about the probability of transitioning from one state to another in some specified interval of time. So $T_{rs}(\delta t)$ would be the probability to be in state $s$ at time $t+\delta t$ given that we were in state $r$ at time $t$.

One can show that these two formulations are related through a matrix exponential.

\begin{equation}
T = e^{Q\delta t}
\end{equation}

#### Continuous Time Being Well Defined

So regarding your first point regarding self transition being well-defined:

- The continuous time formulation requires that the diagonal elements $Q_{rr}$ are equal to the negative sum of all the other transitions ($-\sum_{i\neq r}Q_{ri}$). You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain).
- The `pnext.msm` quantity gives the probability of which state will come next. This is achieved by the equation in your question which just calculates the relative probabilities of transitions.
- Notice that since the diagonal is the negative sum, the equation becomes:
  \begin{equation}
  \frac{-Q_{rs}}{Q_{rr}}=\frac{-Q_{rs}}{-\sum_{i\neq r}Q_{ri}}=\frac{Q_{rs}}{\sum_{i\neq r}Q_{ri}}
  \end{equation}
- So now it is clearly just a relative likelihood!
- Since the continuous time approach asks "Which state comes next?", the answer to that question can never be the current state.

#### Discrete Time Choice of Time Window

Now, let's say we want to look at discrete time and talk about "Which state will we be in 1 second from now?". Then we can easily find our $T$ from $Q$ if we know what our $\delta t$ is.

How do we choose the time window? Well we want a window such that the process is memoryless (Markovian). Often real world processes are non-Markovian on short time scales.

To check for Markovianity, we compute the matrix at a range of windows and examine that the dominant eigenvalue $\lambda$ is insensitive to the precise choice of window.

\begin{equation}
\frac{log(\lambda(\delta t))}{\delta t}\approx \frac{log(\lambda(2\delta t))}{2\delta t}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. So if I understand you correctly I need to do the following: (i) find $\delta t$ such that the largest eigenvalue doesn't change much, (ii) compute the transition probability matrix $T_{rs}(\delta t) = \exp{Q\delta t}$ and present these. Is this correct?

Comment: The time window selection to ensure Markovianity (using my final equation) is if you are calculating your $T$ matrix directly from raw data. If you are just computing $T$ from your calculated $Q$ then Markovianity will be ensured by construction.